# Holistic keyboard shortcut approach/scheme/guide?

Tags: osx, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, macros

### The Question:

Where can I find a resource to help me implement a powerful, holistic, cross-application approach to keyboard shortcuts on MacOS that maximizes productivity and minimizes movement that would hurt my wrists?

### The Explanation:

Recently, I've started having wrist pain related to my keyboard/trackpad use. While I am now taking many proactive steps to address that (ergonomic keyboard, stretches, breaks, adjusting desk), I am also wanting to setup and master a comprehensive set of keyboard shortcuts (on MacOS) that will allow me to:

1. maximize productivity with minimal keystrokes,
2. minimize awkward stretches (ex: moving my left hand from from ASDF to `cmd+ctrl+shift+g`)
3. navigate using the keyboard and avoid the trackpad/mouse whenever possible
4. have an comprehensive and organized approach to shortcuts (ie when I want to define a shortcut in Atom for beautifying the editor there's some logic to why it's `ctrl+option+b` versus `option+shift+b` versus `command+control+option+shift+b`...) rather than a piecemeal, disorganized and application-specific approach.
5. unlearn bad habits (ex: I noticed I move my entire right hand to hit `shift+/` to make a `?`) by defining the good habits.

I have got to believe that someone has already thought this all through and that I don't need to map out existing keyboard shortcuts for different programs, decide on a universal scheme for mapping/remapping that minimizes conflicts/confusion, write my own configuration scripts from the ground up, etc.

#### I am aware of:

- [Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org) for automating OS X actions and assigning to keybindings
- Alfred for quickly doing things via a "command line-like" interface.
- Emacs and Ergomacs, which allow you to define a comprehensive set of keyboard shortcuts *within* the application.

What I'm looking for is essentially an implementation of emacs-like keyboard shortcuts for the whole OS, thoughtfully-organized and ergonomically-friendly

#### The ideal solution would combine:

- A **guide** that orients the user to the approach, principles, etc
- A **software utility** that handles universal mapping of the shortcuts across applications.
- A set of **pre-made config scripts** that implement the beautiful, powerful, sensible approach defined in the guide.

Bonus points if this solution includes window management/resizing/positioning, and makes use of emacs-style [prefix keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Prefix-Keymaps.html#Prefix-Keymaps) to create shortcut "domains" that simplify the shortcuts and group them into logical units.

Answer (score 1):

The best [solution](https://twitter.com/justinhaaheim/status/863130726664949760) I've found to date comes from Will Stern at LearnCode.Academy . He uses an [Ergodox EZ](https://ergodox-ez.com/) keyboard, which allows for multiple layers (ie when you hold down a certain key it activates an entirely different keymap). It also has a "Hyper" key that acts as Ctrl+Cmd+Alt+Shift, which makes it easy to set up shortcuts that won't collide with other pre-existing or program-specific shortcuts. While I intend on ordering an Ergodox, it should be possible to configure a Hyper key on a standard keyboard with other keyboard utilities.

What Will does with his Ergodox configuration is he creates layer with a handful of keys that send `Hyper+[somekey]`, and then binds that key combination to a particular function (like "move a line up") in all his main programs that he uses.